# How to unit test this python class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, serialization, package, factory-pattern

I'm having an issue with the testability of my code. This is related to my class layout and my python package layout.

I hope for one of the following outcomes for this question:

1. a suggestion to change the class layout, or
2. a suggestion to change the package layout, or
3. a hint how to test this stuff without layout changes

### The class hierarchy

The base class is `AuthenticationToken`. The two classes `HardwareToken` and `Keyfile` inherit from it.

`AuthenticationToken`s can be serialized into a string and vice versa. This is how I implement deserialization:

```
class AuthenticationToken(object):

    @classmethod
    def try_deserialize(cls, spec: str):
        for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():
            token = subclass.try_deserialize(spec)
            if token:
                return token
        return None
```

### The python package layout

I have one file per class and put them into a package directory

```
package
+-- __init__.py
+-- authentication_token.py
+-- hardware_token.py
+-- keyfile.py
```

Now I prefer to reference a class like `package.Keyfile` instead of `package.keyfile.Keyfile`. Also all subclass definitions of Authentication token have be seen by python before I can use the `try_derialize` method. This is why I import all classes in `__init__.py`:

```
from .authentication_token import AuthenticationToken
from .hardware_token import HardwareToken
from .keyfile import Keyfile
```

### The testability issue

Now I would like to unit test the `AuthenticationToken` class without referencing its subclasses. The idea is to write a `TestAutheticationToken` class and use it as single subclass during the test:

```
import unittest
from package import AuthenticationToken

class TestSubclass(AuthenticationToken):
    pass

class TestAuthenticationToken(unittest.TestCase):

    # This test fails
    def test_bad_case(self):
        should_be_none = AuthenticationToken.try_deserialize("Keyfile")
        self.assertIsNone(should_be_none)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This test fails because `try_deserialize` creates an object of type `Keyfile`. This is because `__init__.py` is evaluated. This is also the case if I import `AuthenticationToken` directly from the module:

```
from package.authentication_token import AuthenticationToken
```

### The question

So the question is: how can I prevent the classes `Keyfile` and `HardwareToken` from being imported when testing `AuthenticationToken`?

Or otherwise how do I change the class and/or package layout so I can import all classes independtly from each other while still preserving the benefits mentioned above?

Comment: Why have you written your `try_deserialize` in a way that depends on what modules Python has loaded? It sounds like that's the root problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The code is hard to test, because the list of token providers is *implicit*. It depends on which modules have been loaded. I suggest you at least give the *option* of an explicit list of token providers. Either require the token providers to be registered at start up, or provide an optional parameter for the list of token providers.

Here's the simplest change I can think of:

```
class AuthenticationToken(object):

    @classmethod
    def try_deserialize(cls, spec: str, token_providers=None):
        if token_providers is None:
            token_providers = cls.__subclasses__()
        for subclass in token_providers:
            token = subclass.try_deserialize(spec)
            if token:
                return token
        return None
```

Now your regular code is unchanged, and your test can look like this：

```
    def test_bad_case(self):
        should_be_none = AuthenticationToken.try_deserialize(
            "Keyfile",
            token_providers=[TestSubclass])
        self.assertIsNone(should_be_none)
```